# Django log file permissions denied apache2 mod_uwsgi ubuntu

Tags: django, apache, logging, permissions, settings

It seems like by default Django logs errors to apache's error file. On Ubuntu and apache2 this file is /var/log/apache2/error.log and the permissions on the /var/log/apache2 directory is 750 with root as the owner and adm as the group. The permissions on the error.log file itself is 640 with root as the owner and adm as the group.

When errors occur, you can see the stack trace in the error.log file. I want to have django errors in a custom log file, not apache's error log, so I setup the logging config in settings.py. I have a /var/log/example directory and a /var/log/example/myapperrors.log file. I set the permissions exactly like apache2 log directory and error file. However, I get permission denied on the myapperrors.log file.

Comment: But what is your question?

Comment: What should the permissions for my custom error log file be so that django may write to it? And without having to set the permissions to 777 for that file?